# Change Clicked Hover div with background colours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have coded the following hover links that loads content using jQuery into a div. It hovers nicely. As an example i have 4 links (1-4).

When I click a link and once it has loaded, I would like that to become like the way I have styled Link 3. Then when another link is clicked, it needs to re-activate the previous link.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNart/)

Any idea how I can go about doing this?

Thanks.

```
<script>
  function bgColorChange(obj, color){
    obj.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

  function loadContent(page){
    $("#contentPlaceHolder").html("Hello, this is <b>" + page + "</b>!");
  }
</script>


<div onclick="loadContent('link1');" style="border-color: #fff; border-style: solid; border-width: 0 0 1px 0; background-color:#666666; width:200px; line-height:42px; padding-left:10px; color:#fff; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="bgColorChange(this, '#CCCCCC'); this.style.color='#000';" onmouseout="bgColorChange(this, '#666666'); this.style.color='#fff';">Link 1</div>
<div onclick="loadContent('link2');" style="border-color: #fff; border-style: solid; border-width: 0 0 1px 0; background-color:#666666; width:200px; line-height:42px; padding-left:10px; color:#fff; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="bgColorChange(this, '#CCCCCC'); this.style.color='#000';" onmouseout="bgColorChange(this, '#666666'); this.style.color='#fff';">Link 2</div>      
<div style="border-color: #fff; border-style: solid; border-width: 0 0 1px 0; background-color:#CCCCCC; width:200px; line-height:42px; padding-left:10px; color:#000;">Link 3</div>   
<div onclick="loadContent('link4');" style="border-color: #fff; border-style: solid; border-width: 0 0 1px 0; background-color:#666666; width:200px; line-height:42px; padding-left:10px; color:#fff; cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="bgColorChange(this, '#CCCCCC'); this.style.color='#000';" onmouseout="bgColorChange(this, '#666666'); this.style.color='#fff';">Link 4</div>
<div id="contentPlaceHolder" style="float:right;"></div>
```

Comment: Have a look at these answers now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNart/7/)

I added classes:

```
.link{
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    background-color:#666666;
    width:200px;
    line-height:42px;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.link:hover{
    background:#ccc !important;
    color:#000 !important;
}

.link.active{
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    background-color:#CCCCCC !important;
    width:200px;
    line-height:42px;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#000;
}

#contentPlaceHolder{
  float:right;
}
```

So now your HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="link" >Link 1</div>

<div class="link">Link 2</div>

<div class='link active'>Link 3</div>

<div class="link">Link 4</div>

<div id="contentPlaceHolder"></div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$('.link').click(function(e){
    $('.link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('#contentPlaceHolder').html("This is " + $(this).html() + " page!");
});
```

Comment: BeatAlex Thanks that works great. Just one quick question instead of showing the $this.html in the contentPlaceHolder, i am planning to show the id value of the div. so i've replaced that linke with the following, does that look right?: $('#contentPlaceHolder').html("This is " + this.id + " page!");

Comment: or is this better: $('#contentPlaceHolder').html("This is " + $(this).attr('id') + " page!");

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class- clicked/active and write the required css for it and use javascript to add or remove that class on click events!

Comment: This isn't a very good answer and should have probably been a comment.

Comment: and why do you think so? I think all he needed was a way to do what he wanted to do. The code required to achieve it would have been just a couple of google searches away.

Comment: You haven't even given a definitive answer when using the word 'probably'. You have basically said 'It MIGHT be able to do what I've just said, but I'm not actually going to help you with it'.

Comment: Lol. I just saw the other comments. I don't believe in writing the code for them to just copy-paste! It doesn't give the user enough opportunities to learn by trying.

Comment: Maybe not, which in that case you should submit a comment instead, as they're one or two sentence 'answers' and they don't answer anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$("div").click(function(){
 $(".active").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```

**CSS**

```
    div
{
    border-color: #fff; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0; 
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    width:200px;
    line-height:42px; 
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#000;
}
div:hover
{
    background-color:red;

}
.active
{
    background-color:blue;

}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sNart/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave has much room to improve. I suggest to use an unordered list at the first place, with css-defined base and hover background. For this there is no need for JS.

Quicky:

**html:**

```
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li><a href="1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="1">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="1">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="1">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**css:**

```
ul#main_menu {
    list-style: none;
}

ul#main_menu li a {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #777;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
}

ul#main_menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

ul#main_menu li a.activated {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul#main_menu li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('ul#main_menu li a').removeClass('activated');
        $(this).addClass('activated');
    });
});
```

Hope, it helps you out.